# Is running an ajax request every second bad?

Tags: ajax

I am currently trying to create a chat function and notifications function on my site that would get the current users logged in and notifications periodically from a mysql database and right now I have it set to do an ajax call every second to a php page which returns the users online and notifications back in a json object. I am just trying to make sure there isn't a better way of doing this that I can't think of. Also is doing an ajax call to my server so often bad? I would really appreciate any insight on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think web sockets and events will be far more efficient than polling every second.

Comment: I wouldn't say that its bad (I've done it myself before), but you may want to take a look at web sockets and another type of server for real-time chat.

Comment: [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC) might be a good idea, depending on the functionality you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you have a hand full of chatters: no. It is not the best design, but it will do the trick. If you are looking for scalable techniques look for [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) or [Web Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets).